# Spark - How to convert map function output (Row,Row) tuple to one Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write one scenario in Spark using Scala API.
I am passing a user defined function to a Dataframe which processes each row of data frame one by one and returns tuple(Row, Row). How can i change RDD ( Row, Row) to Dataframe (Row)? See below code sample -

```
**Calling map function-**
    val df_temp = df_outPut.map { x => AddUDF.add(x,date1,date2)}
**UDF definition.**
    def add(x: Row,dates: String*): (Row,Row) = {
......................
........................
    var result1,result2:Row = Row()
..........
    return (result1,result2)
```

Now df_temp is a RDD(Row1, Row2). my requirement is to make it one RDD or Dataframe by breaking tuple elements to 1 record of RDD or Dataframe
RDD(Row). Appreciate your help.

Comment: How would you like the two Row elements to be combined? Should the columns from the second be appended to those of the first? Might there be common columns that exist in both rows? Question is unclear without this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten your Row tuples, say if we start from this example *rdd*:

```
rddExample.collect()
// res37: Array[(org.apache.spark.sql.Row, org.apache.spark.sql.Row)] = Array(([1,2],[3,4]), ([2,1],[4,2]))

val flatRdd = rddExample.flatMap{ case (x, y) => List(x, y) }
// flatRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[45] at flatMap at <console>:35
```

To convert it to data frame.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType}

val schema = StructType(StructField("x", IntegerType, true)::
                        StructField("y", IntegerType, true)::Nil)    
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(flatRdd, schema)
df.show
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
|  2|  1|
|  4|  2|
+---+---+
```